# When should I add campden tablets?

Tags: cider, campden

So I'm still pretty new to home brewing, I recently finished my first batch of cider from a kit and the end results where ok. Nothing amazing, but it was something I made and feels extra rewarding.

Now onto the question, I plan to start my 2nd brew tomorrow, again, from a cider kit ([This kit to be precise](http://www.wilko.com/cider+beer-brewing/wilko-forest-fruits-cider-kit/invt/0318709)). I will be using tap water for my brew, since it's not really possible for me to transport 20 litres (5 gallons) of bottled water, without a car. I want to know, at what stage should I add my campden tablet(s) to remove all chlorine from the water?

Should I put the water in the bucket tonight, add the tablet(s) and then leave it 24hr, before adding the mixture, sugar and yeast?

Or, should I wait till tomorrow, add the sugar and mixture, then add the tablets and wait 24 hours before adding the yeast?

Bonus Question: Best ways to add carbonation to my cider? The sugar added into he pressure keg created lots of c02 to push the liquid out the tap, but the cider itself is flat when tasting.

Thanks and sorry for the long post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tablets work pretty much instantaneoulsy, so as long as you crush the tabs well before using them (keep in mind that 1 will treat up to 20 gal.) and give then 5 min. to work, you'll be fine.

As to your CO2 question, you need to have a CO2 tank to dispense.  The sugar you added will carb the cider, but you'll lose it all if you don't add more CO2 to dispense.

Comment: I thought it took around 24 hours for the tablets to fully desolve though, so adding the yeast within that time, could result in the tablets acting against the yeast I want to make the alcohol. I actually purchased a packet of the powder in the tablets that kills the chlorine, as opposed to actual tablets hat require crushing, so that bit is already covered :)

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid you were incorrectly informed.  Within minutes you'll be fine.

Comment: Good to know, Thanks. One last thing, when it the best time to add it? When it's just water? or when the water, kit and sugar has been added?

Comment: Add it to the water before you use it.